# Probability of a three-pairs in 6-card poker

Tags: probability

Suppose out of a deck of 52 regular playing cards, you are dealt a hand of 6 cards. What is the probability of you getting a three-pair hand? That is, three faces that each appear twice.

I've worked out $${\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{2}\over\binom{52}{6}}\approx0.01821$$

as the answer, since you're picking three faces and any two suits. Is this correct, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good thought, but you're overcounting. For example, your numbers would suggest that the following are different: (1) a pair of aces, then a pair of twos, then a pair of sixes and (2) a pair of sixes, then a pair of aces, then a pair of twos. Due to this overcounting, your answer is precisely $6$ times as large as it should be, since you're counting each ordered arrangement of the three pairs differently, and there are $3!=6$ ways to arrange $3$ distinct objects in order.

Rather, to determine the faces, we use instead $\binom{13}{3}$ to prevent such overcounting (since we're choosing $3$ of the $13$ possible face values). Then we use $\binom{4}{2}$ for each face (since we're choosing $2$ of the available $4$ suits for each face), so we have: $$\frac{\binom{13}3\cdot\binom{4}{2}^3}{\binom{52}{6}}$$

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that you’re not including the cases in which two of the pairs make a four-of-a-kind. There are $\binom{13}3$ ways to choose the denominations of the the $3$ pairs, and for each pair there are $\binom42$ ways to choose the two suits, so there are altogether $\binom{13}3\binom42^3=286\cdot6^3=61,776$ such hands, and the probability of getting one is

$$\frac{\binom{13}3\binom42^3}{\binom{52}6}=\frac{61,776}{20,358,520}\approx0.0030344\;.$$

Your figure is too large, because you’re counting a pair of twos, a pair of threes, and a pair of fours as a different hand from a pair of threes, a pair of twos, and a pair of fours: you’re counting each hand $6$ times, once for each permutation of the three denominations.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose out of a deck of 52 regular playing cards, you are dealt a hand of 6 cards. What is the probability of you getting a three-pair hand? That is, three faces that each appear twice. This question was posted almost 7 years ago and the consensus was that the probability was about .0030344.
There are (133) ways to choose the denominations of the the 3 pairs, and for each pair there are (42) ways to choose the two suits, so there are altogether (133)(42)3=286⋅63=61,776 such hands, and the probability of getting one is

(133)(42)3(526)=61,77620,358,520≈0.0030344.
What if the restriction was placed on this problem that the hand needed to look like this for instance 7 of spades and 7 of clubs, K of hearts and K of diamonds, and 10 of clubs and 10 of spades? the pairs would have to be the same color.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please ignore the previous post.  Some junk was  posted!!!Suppose out of a deck of 52 regular playing cards, you are dealt a hand of 6 cards. What is the probability of you getting a three-pair hand? That is, three faces that each appear twice. This question was posted almost 7 years ago and the consensus was that the probability was about .0030344. 
What if the restriction was placed on this problem that the hand needed to look like this for instance 7 of spades and 7 of clubs, K of hearts and K of diamonds, and 10 of clubs and 10 of spades? the pairs would have to be the same color.